# PHP use object to store other object into database PDO

Tags: php

I'm a bit lost trying to learn OOPHP. This isn't finalized code by any means, but I'm just trying to learn how I can store an object into the database using another object.

I read that I should convert the object being passed into an array, so I just typecast it, but I didn't want to use

```
class ObjectStorage {
    private $myObject;

    function __construct($object) {
        $this->myObject = (array)$object;
    }

    function __get($attribute) {
        return var_dump($this->$attribute);
    }

    public function saveVideo($conn) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (`src`, `title`, `desc`, `cat_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($this->myObject);

        echo "Video Saved!";
}
```

}

When running the get to see what's in myObject I get this

```
array(4) {
    ["Videosrc"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["Videotitle"]=>
    string(5) "Title"
    ["Videodesc"]=>
    string(4) "Desc"
    ["Videocat"]=>
    string(3) "Cat"
}
```

I can't figure out how to access those. Could someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something following should do**

Just change your constructor
if  your database columns are named after object property names.

```
function __construct($object) {
    $bind = array();
    foreach($object as $prop => $val) {
        $bind[":$prop"] = $val;
    }
    $this->myObject = $bind;
}
```

In your example seems that your object props are with different name than database columns, so since PDO prepare array keys have to map database columns you could do something like this.

```
function __construct($object) {
    $bind = array();
    $bind[':src'] = $object->Videosrc;
    $bind[':title'] = $object->Videotitle;
    $bind[':desc'] = $object->Videodesc;
    $bind[':cat_id'] = $object->Videocat;
    $this->myObject = $bind;
}
```

And your INSERT query should look something like this

```
"INSERT INTO videos (`src`, `title`, `desc`, `cat_id`) VALUES (:src, :title, :desc, :cat_id)"
```

Comment: Oh, my object has cat instead of cat_id, if I change the attribute to cat_id and add that foreach loop it'll work?

Comment: Edited answer, you should modify also insert query. And for your comment seems that your object has properties ex:`Videosrc` instead of `src` so in that case you have to use second option.

Comment: Well the actual properties of the object are src, title, desc, cat, but when I typecast it to an array it adds the class name to the front because they're protected. Trying to access $object->src doesn't work. Do I need to make the properties public, that would be bad, yeah?

Comment: in general public props might not be first choice. Check this comment PHP doc get_object_vars http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php#47075

Comment: Nevermind, it worked once I removed the ? and changed to :src, :title, :desc, :cat_id like in your edit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Ryan Deming My answer covers everything you wrote into your answer. Good practice is either upvote or accept the answer if it answered your question instead of posting same code again :)

Comment: Oh I see  I can accept the answer. I upvoted it but I don't have 15 reputation so it said it won't display it publicly. I checked yours off and deleted the one I posted. Thanks again!